# Unable to add multiple style with ngStyle

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to add a height and width style to an img element using ngStyle:

```
<img class="image-full-view" [ngStyle]="{'height': selectedImage.heightSize, 'width': selectedImage.widthSize}" [src]="selectedImage.imagePath" alt="Man Praying">
```

The image information comes from an object which is created in a service file:

```
 private images = [
        new Image('Man Praying', 1, 'Cambodia', 'Man praying to Sun', '£100', '../../assets/Images/Cambodia/Praying to the Sun.JPG', '250px', '800px'), 
]
```

The height is 250px and the width is 800px.

This is where the object constructor is created in a separate model file:

```
export class Image {
public name: string;
public id: number;
public album: string;
public description: string;
public price: any;
public imagePath: string;
public heightSize: any;
public widthSize: any;


constructor(name: string, id: number, album: string, description: string, price: any, imagePath: string, heightSize: any, widthSize: any) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.album = album;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.heightSize = heightSize;
    this.widthSize = widthSize;
}
}
```

The image height is correctly applied to the element but the width is not. I have confirmed this by inspecting the element using Chrome dev tools. Is there something I am missing here as I can't seem to see what the issue is?

This is how the element shows in the chrome dev tools:

```
<img _ngcontent-vxx-c18="" alt="Man Praying" class="image-full-view" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" src="../../assets/Images/Cambodia/Praying to the Sun.JPG" style="height: 250px;">
```

I have checked all my code to make sure the images width is not set in another style sheet.

Comment: based on the rendered element, `widthSize` isn't set correctly on the `Image` object

Comment: I've just realised that I put the wrong components img tag on my OP. The issue still stands though. I have thoroughly checked my code and I still can't see where the issue lies. I will update the post with some additional info

Comment: not directyl related but you can short hand basically your entire image object like `class Image { constructor(public name: string, public id; number, ... etc ..., public widthSize: any) { } }` and avoid writing all the properties and assignments

Comment: Thanks bryan, I'll remember this

Comment: have you tried to log and see the value of widthsize ?

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple ngStyles you can add a methode that return it :

**HTML:**

```
[ngStyle]="imageStyle()"
```

**TS:**

```
imageStyle(): object {
    return {
        height: this.image.heightSize ? this.image.heightSize : '',
        width: this.image.widthSize ? this.image.widthSize : ''
    };
}
```

Comment: what is not true

Comment: your answer. you do not need a method to return to use multiple styles in ngStyle and doing this is very bad practice as it's a performance drag

Comment: Thanks for the response Aymen by bryan is right, you can set multiple styles directly to ngStyle

Comment: function calls in template evaluate on every change detection cycle. literals do not. function calls in template should always be avoided

Comment: but it is necessary if you need a dinamically styling

Answer (score -1):

Seems as though the semi colon in the object constructor was the issue:

```
export class Image {
    public name: string;
    public id: number;
    public album: string;
    public description: string;
    public price: any;
    public imagePath: string;
    public heightSize: any;
    public widthSize: any


    constructor(name: string, id: number, album: string, description: string, price: any, imagePath: string, heightSize: any, widthSize: any) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.album = album;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.heightSize = heightSize;
        this.widthSize = widthSize;
    }
}
```

With bryan recommendation:

```
    export class Image {

    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public id: number,
        public album: string,
        public description: string,
        public price: any,
        public imagePath: string,
        public heightSize: any,
        public widthSize: any) {}
}
```

Silly mistake!

Comment: Why the down vote? This resolved the issue. I appreciate it was a typo error but I'm confused by the down vote